# Twiddle wakka for semantic versioning

Tags: ruby, semantic-versioning

From [thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-pessimistic-operator):

> ~> 1.1 means that when you bundle install, you’ll get the highest-released gem version of thin between the range >= 1.1 and < 2.0
>
> ~> 3.0.3 means that when you bundle install, you’ll get the highest-released gem version of rails between the range >= 3.0.3 and < 3.1

From [semver 2.0](http://semver.org/):

```
Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:

MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
```

So then will `~>0.1.0` take you from `1.0.0 > x >= 0.1.0`?

Also, is the `v1.0.0` what people are referring to when they say they are working to "get the `one point oh` version" out the door? Even when there are two 0s after the 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically with the twiddle-waka (`~>`), only the last digit can change.

`~> 0.1.0` will not take you to anything beyond `0.1.x`, hence not `1.0.0`, not even `0.2.0`.

In my opinion, to specify a version following semver intents, one would specify a minor twiddle-waka, eg. `~> 0.2`. Thus you get functionality upgrades (to `0.3(.x)`, `0.4(.x)`, `0.x.y`, even `0.10.99`!), but not backwards-breaking changes (to `1.0` or `1.0.x`).

And if you want to be able to have `MAJOR` change, so to go from `1.0` to `2.0` and `9.0` on the same spec, then I guess you don't really have a version specification! ;o)

That being said, some gems that are more fundamental/central to your project will probably benefit from being followed more closely, with a patch-level `~>`, eg. `~> 4.2.17`. (That's a strategy I employ for instance with Rails in a Rails project.) Basically, anything that would make the upgrade/step-up non-trivial.

(and yes, mentioning "one point oh" includes `1.0.0`, `1.0.1` and so on)

Comment: so `~>0.1` would take you potentially up to `0.9.99` and `~>1.0` would take you potentially up to `9.99.99`?

Comment: `~> 0.1` matches `0.9.99`, yes. `~> 1.0` matches `1.9.99` but not anything beyond `2.0`, hence not `9.9.x`. If `MAJOR` can change, then I guess you don't have a version specification ;o)